# How do medals and medal punchcard work?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Is there any sort of strategy I should be doing to gain the most efficient EXP out of the medal punchcards? What are the best medals for earning EXP? Does it matter what medal is earned at each punchcard slot?

How do medals and medal punchcard work?

Answer (score 1):

From what i can tell you just get them as you go from looting, surviving and killing. They refresh every 24 hours and are spent towards exp as far as i know. They “rank up” as you go and i assume that will determine how much experience you get.